# Print the maximum non perfect square

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make a c++ program that finds the maximum non perfect square in an array and print it, perfect square i.e. `x = y^2 => 4 = 2^2`.

Here is what I've tried and doesn't work for me, don't know why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        cin >> arr[i];
        sqrt(arr[i]);

        if ((arr[i] * 10) % 10 == 0)
            arr[i] = arr[1];
        else
            arr[i] = arr[0];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[0] < arr[i])
            arr[0] = arr[i];
    }
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My logic is to take the square root of each array element and check if it's non-perfect or perfect. If we multiply the element by 10, then take modulus of 10, then we know whether it is an integer or decimal. For example: 2*10 = 20, 20%10 = 0 (perfect square), otherwise it is not perfect. Then, I stored each non-perfect square in `arr[0]`, in the next loop I'm supposed to find the largest non perfect square and print it. What am I doing wrong?

**PS:**
Consider `arr[variable]` is valid, because it works in CodeBlocks. Thank you!

Comment: Need a bit more here: `sqrt(arr[i]);`. Looks like you are tossing away the result.

Comment: You could do `arr[i]=sqrt(arr[i])`

Comment: However, I do not seem to understand.  You are printing the largest non-perfect square in the array, right?

Comment: @XcoderX yes I'm printing the largest non perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

You lost the result of `sqrt`. `sqrt(arr[i])` does not change `arr[i])`.

You improperly check if a square root is an integral. You should cast a result of `sqrt` to int, multiply it by itself and compare with `arr[i]`.

I left you free to update your code properly yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int k[n];
  double arr[n];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    cin>>k[i];
    arr[i]=sqrt(k[i]);
    int j = arr[i];
    if (arr[i]==j){
      arr[i]=0;
      }
    }
  double m=0;
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (arr[i]>m){
      m=arr[i];
      index = i;
    }
  }
  cout << k[index];
}
```

Here is a code.  We introduce a `double`, such that it can store the decimals.  Then we introduce an integer.  If the square root of the number is a decimal, it is not a perfect square.  However, when I introduce this integer `j`, it will convert `arr[i]` to an integer.  If the number is a perfect square, then `arr[i]` is an integer, and `j==arr[i]`.  We do not want that, so we put that equal `0`.  We find the largest array, and mark the index.  Then we print out the original number in the original array with that index.  i have added this as `float` does not store every single decimal point.

To clarify: lets say `arr[i]=4.55556`.  Then `j=4`.  `arr[i]!=j`. If `arr[i]=5`, `j=5`, `arr[i]=j`, and then `arr[i]` is set to `0`.

Comment: lets say arr[i] is 4.55556.  Then j is 4.  arr[i]!=j. If arr[i] is 5, j is 5, arr[i]=j.  Please think logically here.

Comment: at the back i introduce m, which is the max of the square rooted values.  I square it to get k.

Comment: apparently it does.  I tried 1,2,4,5 and it gives 5

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549941/perfect-square-and-perfect-cube/1549960#1549960) logic to find if a number is perfect-square or not, this is one way to find  largest non perfect square of an `array` of positive numbers, initialize `answer=-1` before you enter the loop, `n` is the size of the array

```
double answer = -1,temp;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){                                       
    if((temp = array[i]) != (sqrt(array[i])*sqrt(array[i]))){
        if(temp > answer){
            answer = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably going to [need some epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) in here `(temp = array[i]) != (sqrt(array[i])*sqrt(array[i]))` because equals with doubles is iffy due to imprecision. Side note: 2 `sqrt`s is pretty expensive. Might be worth `sqrt`ing once and caching the result.

Comment: Improper solution.