# Finding sum in less than O(N)

Tags: algorithm, math

**Question:**
In less O(n) find a number K in sequence 1,2,3...N such that sum of 1,2,3...K is exactly half of sum of 1,2,3..N

**Maths:**
I know that the sum of the sequence 1,2,3....N is **N(N+1)/2**.

Therefore our task is to find K such that:
**K(K+1) = 1/2 * (N)(N+1)/2** if such a K exists.

**Pseudo-Code:**

```
sum1 = n(n+1)/2
sum2 = 0

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    sum2 += i;
    if(sum2 == sum1)
    {
        index = i
        break;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The solution is **O(n)** but I need better such as **O(n), O(log(n))...**

Comment: Because of a certain question in codechef which involves the following trick and has tight constraints

Comment: you stopped doing the maths too early. Solve `K(K+1) = 1/2 * (N)(N+1)/2` for `K` then you get the result in constant time

Comment: You have to solve [Quadratic_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)

Comment: My guess would be the solution is O(K)... burn me on a pile if I am wrong :)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++k%28k%2B1%29%2F2+%3D+%28N%29%28N%2B1%29%2F4+for+k

Comment: Come on - simply finding an analytical solution is considered cheating in 2020. At least you need a grid of supercomputers, some deep neural networks, numpy and what not and make the grid "learn" the solution AI style ;)

Comment: But how to check if (2N^2 + 2N + 1) is a perfect square (is there any way to say if float value is an integer than output  K)

Comment: how to check? Your problem statement assumes that there exists a solution. If not the problem statement is faulty, not the solution

Comment: well, more consttructive: once you have the candiate for `K`  you just need to go back to K(K+1) = 1/2 * (N)(N+1)/2  to see if lhs and rhs are really equal. There are no floats in that formula

Comment: `bool is_square(int value) {int square_root = sqrt(value); return square_root * square_root  == value; }`.

Comment: See approach 2 mentioned in this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-given-number-sum-first-n-natural-numbers). It is `O(logn)`. It's surely is not as efficient as the one suggested in the answers.

Comment: "The solution is O(n) but I need better such as O(n), " ???

Comment: @user3386109: this condition is by far insufficient.

Comment: Your solution is wrong, as you consider that N is known upfront. But it isn't !

Comment: Triangular numbers that are twice other triangular numbers: https://oeis.org/A029549

Comment: Algorithms and their Big O notation are language-independent, so please don't tag this with any language.

Comment: Is `O(x) | x < N/2` considered "better" than `O(N)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close with your equation, but you dropped the divide by 2 from the K side. You actually want

```
K * (K + 1) / 2 = N * (N + 1) / (2 * 2)
```

Or

```
2 * K * (K + 1) = N * (N + 1)
```

Plugging that into wolfram alpha gives the real solutions:

```
K = 1/2 * (-sqrt(2N^2 + 2N + 1) - 1)
K = 1/2 * (sqrt(2N^2 + 2N + 1) - 1)
```

Since you probably don't want the negative value, the second equation is what you're looking for. That should be an O(1) solution.

Comment: But how to check if (2N^2 + 2N + 1) is a perfect square (is there any way to say if float value is an integer than output K)

Comment: I am not sure that N is a given.

Comment: @YvesDaoust `N` is the only given in OP's pseudo-code. Also "Find K in the sequence 1, 2 3, ..., N" reads to me like N is given. I'm not sure how else this could be solved...

Comment: @scohe001: by searching a pair (K, N) that works. If N is given, the question is so trivial...

Comment: @Yves then doesn't it just become an Algebra problem? What would be the point of writing any code? I'd say that'd be far more trivial from a programming perspective. Your whole program would just be `std::cout << "The answer is ...";`

Comment: @scohe001: it is the converse. If N is known, the answer boils down to a boring `cout << "The answer is " <<`  followed by the quadratic root formula. If not and you really want to design a program that does the search (ignoring that K=2, N=3 fits) in a non exhaustive way,  there comes the true challenge.

Comment: @Alpha if the number isn't a perfect square then there is no solution to the problem as stated. Take for example N = 4 ->1,2,3,4 adds up to 10. There's no K that will give you exactly half. If the question states "what's the largest K less than or equal to half" or "what's the smallest K greater than or equal to half" then there's always a solution and you just round up or round down the solution you get from the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers show the analytical solutions of the equation

```
k * (k + 1) = n * (n + 1) / 2            Where n is given
```

The OP needs **k** to be a whole number, though, and such value may not exist for every chosen **n**.

We can adapt the Newton's method to solve this equation using only integer arithmetics.

```
sum_n =  n * (n + 1) / 2
k = n
repeat indefinitely         // It usually needs only a few iterations, it's O(log(n))
    f_k = k * (k + 1)
    if  f_k == sum_n
        k is the solution, exit
    if  f_k < sum_n
        there's no k, exit 
    k_n = (f_k - sum_n) / (2 * k + 1)   // Newton step: f(k)/f'(k) 
    if  k_n == 0
        k_n = 1   // Avoid inifinite loop
    k = k - k_n;
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/r6cce8) there is a C++ implementation.

---

We can find all the pairs (**n**, **k**) that satisfy the equation for 0 < **k** < **n** ≤ **N** adapting the algorithm posted in the question.

```
n = 1                        // This algorithm compares 2 * k * (k + 1) and n * (n + 1)
sum_n = 1                    // It finds all the pairs (n, k) where 0 < n ≤ N in O(N)
sum_2k = 1
for every n <= N             // Note that n / k → sqrt(2) when n → ∞
    while  sum_n < sum_2k
        n = n + 1            // This inner loop requires a couple of iterations,
        sum_n = sum_n + n    // at most.
   
    if ( sum_n == sum_2k )
        print n and k
   
    k = k + 1
    sum_2k = sum_2k + 2 * k
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/T39evr) there is an implementation in C++ that can find the first pairs where **N** < 200,000,000:

```
           N           K           K * (K + 1)
----------------------------------------------
           3           2                     6
          20          14                   210
         119          84                  7140
         696         492                242556
        4059        2870               8239770
       23660       16730             279909630
      137903       97512            9508687656
      803760      568344          323015470680
     4684659     3312554        10973017315470
    27304196    19306982       372759573255306
   159140519   112529340     12662852473364940
```

Of course it becomes impractical for too large values and eventually overflows.

Besides, there's a *far better* way to find all those pairs (have you noticed the patterns in the sequences of the last digits?).

We can start by manipulating this [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation):

```
2k(k + 1) = n(n + 1)
                                   introducing   u = n + 1   →   n = u - 1
                                                 v = k + 1       k = v - 1
2(v - 1)v = (u - 1)u
2(v2 - v) = u2 + u
2(4v2 - 4v) = 4u2 + 4u
2(4v2 - 4v) + 2 = 4u2 - 4u + 2
2(4v2 - 4v + 1) = (4u2 - 4u + 1) + 1
2(2v - 1)2 = (2u - 1)2 + 1
                                 substituting   x = 2u - 1   →   u = (x + 1)/2
                                                y = 2v - 1       v = (y + 1)/2

2y2 = x2 + 1
x2 - 2y2 = -1
```

Which is the negative [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) for 2.

It's easy to find its fundamental solutions by inspection, **x**<sub>1</sub> = 1 and **y**<sub>1</sub> = 1. Those would correspond to **n** = **k** = 0, a solution of the original Diophantine equation, but not of the original problem (I'm ignoring the sums of 0 terms).

Once those are known, [we can calculate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Additional_solutions_from_the_fundamental_solution) all the other ones with two simple recurrence relations

```
xi+1 = xi + 2yi
yi+1 = yi + xi
```

Note that we need to "skip" the even **y**s as they would lead to non integer solutions. So we can directly use theese

```
xi+2 = 3xi + 4yi   →   ui+1 = 3ui + 4vi - 3  →   ni+1 = 3ni + 4ki + 3
yi+2 = 2xi + 3yi       vi+1 = 2ui + 3vi - 2      ki+1 = 2ni + 3ki + 2
```

Summing up:

```
                    n                         k
-----------------------------------------------
3* 0 + 4* 0 + 3 =   3      2* 0 + 3* 0 + 2 =  2  
3* 3 + 4* 2 + 3 =  20      2* 3 + 3* 2 + 2 = 14  
3*20 + 4*14 + 3 = 119      2*20 + 3*14 + 2 = 84  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is asking to solve the diophantine equation

```
2K(K+1) = N(N+1).
```

By inspection, `K=2`, `N=3` is a solution !

---

Note that technically this is an O(1) problem, because N has a finite value and does not vary (and if no solution exists, the dependency on N is even meanignless).

Answer (score -1):

The condition you have is that the sum of 1..N is twice the sum of 1..K

So you have `N(N+1) = 2K(K+1)` or `K^2 + K - (N^2 + N) / 2 = 0`

Which means `K = (-1 +/- sqrt(1 + 2(N^2 + N)))/2`

Which is O(1)

Comment: But how to check if (2N^2 + 2N + 1) is a perfect square (is there any way to say if float value is an integer than output K)

Comment: @Alpha that's a fairly simply O(1) check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549960/2602718

Comment: @Alpha you don't need to check the perfect number, you need to round it up. That should do it.

Comment: @kvantour since the problem definition from OP mentions "*is exactly half of sum*," I'd guess printing that no such `K` exists is a correct solution (as opposed to just rounding up).